# Add colon {:} after the chapter number in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, punctuation

My Table of Contents is displayed like this

```
Chapter 1 Introduction.....................................................1
```

How I can add the colon after the number so it displays as

```
Chapter 1: Introduction....................................................1
```

I am using this macro codes

```
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\space}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\widthof{\textbf{Appendix~999~}}}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}%
    }%
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917). At the very least we need to know what `\documentclass{...}` you are using, otherwise there is no way of answering.

Comment: Please modify the @chapter macro in the book.cls by adding the below  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}                                {\protect\numberline{\thechapter:}#1}

Comment: We generally do not go off site to get examples as links tend to rot over time, thus making your question unusable for others in the future. This please update your question with a full (but minimal, we are not interested in your entire thesis) self contained example

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant pieces of code _here_. Links to external files are discouraged because your question might become meaningless if/when the link disappears (next week, or next year, or... ).

Comment: Thank you , I added the macro codes

Answer (score 4):

It is not usual to have the word Chapter before the number in the ToC. Perhaps the `tocloft` package was used for this? But as you have shown no code that is just a guess, or perhaps it is part of the class that you are using, which you haven't told us about.

You can use the `tocloft` package to put a colon after the chapter number.

```
% tocprob.tex SE 526130 Colon in ToC

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

I have never come across code that limits the number of chapters in a document. If you want an answer to that please ask another question and provide an MWE (from `\documentclass... to`\end{document}`) that we can compile which includes the minimal amount of code that illustrates your problem. GOM

**EDIT** In a comment the OP asked how to remove the colon from the appendix.
There is a macro `\addtocontents{<file>}{<text>}` that when called inserts the `<text>` into the `<file>` (`toc` or `lof` or `lot` or ...). To stop the appendix colon then something along these lines (untested):

```
...
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersum}{}}
\appendix
...
```

and if you later want to restore the colon

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I added this command line to the macro  \renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:} and it adds the colon as I want but it adds the colon also to the appendix, how I can remove it from the appendix

Comment: You are right there was a mistake and I fixed it, now there is no limitation in the number of chapters. So can you please help me in limiting the colon only to chapters, I don't want it to also appear in the appendices

Comment: @user205772 I have extended my answer to cater for your extended question.